# How to determine coordinate (+-) of point on 1-dimensional axis?

Tags: geometry

I do have three points on the line which mark my 1-dimensional coordinate system:

- A (0 coordinate),
- B (fixed point; indicates positive direction of axis)
- C (a variable point somewhere on the line)

I know the distances AC, AB, BC.

I know that if AC + BC = AB then C must be somewhere between A and B and therefore (+).

**Question:** What if C is either to the left or right of AB? Can we determine whether AC should be negated (-) on the scale or not?

Comment: If $C$ is to the left of $AB$, then $AC + AB = BC$; if $C$ is to the right of $AB$, then $AB + BC = AC$ (just draw them out). Make your deductions from there.

Comment: Thank you so much, that helped a lot!